# Segmentation Error in C++ program

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to find the sum of two binary numbers. My approach is to store individual bits in an array and then print the output which is also stored in an array of size one more than the previous two arrays. Also the size of both the binary numbers is same. So I wrote the following code and since I am getting started with c++ so I write it using classes. I just want to know why am I getting 'Segmentation error(core dumped)'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class arrays{
private:
    int n;
public:
    void input(){
        cout<<"Enter the size of arrays ";
        cin>>n;
    }

    void array_creation(vector<int>Z){
        long int b;
        int a;
        cout<<"Enter the binary number ";
        cin>>b;
        while(b!=0){
            a=b%10;
            Z.push_back(a);
            b=b/10;
        }
        Z[-1]=0;
    }

    void output(vector<int>Z){
        cout<<"The sum of two binary numbers is ";
        for(int a=0;a<n+1;a++)
            cin>>Z[a];
    }

    void logic_set(vector<int>Z,vector<int>Y,vector<int>X){
        for(int a=n-1;a>=0;a--){
            if(Z[a]==0 && Y[a]==0)
                X[a+1]=0;
            if(Z[a]==0 && Y[a]==1)
                X[a+1]=1;
            if(Z[a]==1 && Y[a]==0)
                X[a+1]=1;
            if(Z[a]==1 && Y[a]==1){
                X[a+1]=0;
            label:
                if(Z[a-1]==0)
                    Z[a-1]=1;
                if(Z[a-1]==1)
                    Z[a-1]==2;
            }
            if(Z[a]==2){
                X[a+1]==Y[a];
                goto label;
            }
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    arrays a,b;
    vector<int>A;
    vector<int>B;
    vector<int>C;
    a.input();
    a.array_creation(A);
    b.array_creation(B);
    a.logic_set(A,B,C);
    a.output(C);
}
```

This is the exact error just in case
[The exact error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjeKI.png)

Comment: First, run it in a debugger and find out exactly where it crashes and maybe even find out why. You also have undefined behaviour in your code and I can't imagine why you'd have it. Indexing with `-1`, why?

Comment: `Z[-1]=0;` looks like an obvious problem.

Comment: Why are you using a `goto` statement?

Comment: Protip: Replace all indexing operations `foo[bar]` by `foo.at(bar)`.

Comment: The `vector<int>` instance that `a.logic_set` is using is not the same as `a.array_creation`.

Comment: **All** of your function parameters are by-value, so if you expect any modifications to the caller's arguments once a function completes, that's not going to happen. Both `logic_set` and `array_creation` are afflicted with this problem. You should either (a) investigate how *references* are used in the language, and/or (b) perhaps use those return types for something besides `void`.

Comment: Snark off to the side for a moment, there are good uses of `goto` that will result in better code. This is not one of them, especially with the odd indentation hiding the flow of the code.

Comment: You're accessing `X[a+1]` but at no point in your program do you actually make vector `X` bigger, it's always an empty vector -- you're writing to a place in memory that's not properly allocated by vector.

Comment: You should format your code better to make it more readable. That's easier for those willing to help.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen:  `list[-1]` is valid Python - it's the same as `vector.back()` in C++.  I think there are other languages that have the same convention.  Obviously, it doesn't work in C++.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. Your question really is why your get segmentation error in a c++ program.

Comment: @MartinBonner Ah, true. Could be from languages like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also  array_creation will not populate the vector as the argument is passed by value, so you will get a temporary object populated instead.
You should be using a reference instead.

array_creation(vector & Z)